# How do multiple goto labels work

Tags: c, function, goto, callstack

Quick question:

Let's say I am working in C code and I call a goto to go to a specific label, but I have multiple labels as such:

```
goto A;

   A:
   //something
   B:
   //something else
   C:
   //something else
```

When I goto A, will I also execute B and C or will I simply exit the function?

Comment: It will do what it tells: just `goto` label `A`.

Comment: I am curious, why would it exit the function?

Comment: Why ask something like this? This would take less than a minute to check.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be tested by the user easily (there is no need to ask).

Answer (score 4):

A label is just an anchor in the code. It is not code, the label itself is not executed. The `goto` statement "jumps" to the statement labelled (prefixed) with the label that is present in the `goto` statement. The code continues to run from there and the execution follows all the rules as before (regarding if/else branches, loops, return, all the stuff).

The code does not "exit" a function; it "returns" from a function when the execution reaches a `return` statement. If there is no `return` statement in the function's body then it returns when the execution reaches the function's body closing curly bracket (`}`).

Answer (score -2):

add return after every label like==

```
goto A;
   A:
   //something
return;
   B:
   //something else
return;
   C:
   //something else
```

no need in the last one
enjoy....